# List of all websites visited using Chrome, but only list them once

Tags: google-chrome

I need to pull the list of browsing history from google, but show each website only once. This is because I lost my Tabs and all Session and Tabs were overwritten.

I can only restore tabs from history but there are links which appear each day as some sites I use more often than others, like emails.

If I look at Google History, it shows some links appear every day, which I do not want. Can i get a list of all websites I visited, but the list only show them once. I could then click them and restore.

Many thanks.

Comment: You could remove the duplicates. Google "remove duplicate lines" and you find stuff like https://dedupelist.com/ & 
https://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-duplicate-lines-online.php & 
https://pinetools.com/remove-duplicate-lines Are the lines exact duplicates of eachother?

Comment: What OS are you running?